SQLalchemy doesn't return null values
I am building a FastAPI app. My database is MySQL.
Every time I try to fetch a user with null columns it was skipping everything that was null in my database. Also the result is a tuple so I cannot know which value belongs in which column.
I am trying to get a user from the database like this:
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, create_engine, Session, select, update
from typing import AsyncGenerator
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, load_only
from sqlalchemy import join, func
import os

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@localhost/events")

class Users(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    email: str
    username: str
    password: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    birth_date: Optional[datetime] = None
    student_id: Optional[int] = None
    profile_picture: str
    createdon: datetime
    role: str
    disabled: bool

class Roles(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    role: str



def get_user_by_id(id):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(
                Users.id,
                Users.username,
                Users.email,
                Users.firstname,
                Users.lastname,
                Users.birth_date,
                Roles.role,
                )  \
            .select_from(join(Users, Roles, Users.role == Roles.id)) \
            .where(Users.id == id)
        user = session.exec(statement).fetchone()
        print (user)
        user_dict = {
            "id": user[0],
            "username": user[1],
            "email": user[2],
            "firstname": user[3],
            "lastname": user[4],
            "student_id": user[5],
            "birth_date": user[6],
            "profile_picture": user[7],
            "role": user[8]
        }
        return user_dict

the result that I get is this:
(18, 'test2@test.com', 'password')
I tried doing this but didn't do anything:
 statement = select(
                Users.id,
                func.coalesce(Users.username, "").label('username'),
                func.coalesce(Users.email, "").label('email'),
                func.coalesce(Users.firstname, "").label('firstname'),
                func.coalesce(Users.lastname, "").label('lastname'),
                func.coalesce(Users.student_id, "").label('student_id'),
                func.coalesce(Users.birth_date, "").label('birth_date'),
                func.coalesce(Users.profile_picture, "").label('profile_picture'),
                func.coalesce(Roles.role, "").label('role'),            
                )  \
            .select_from(Users.join(Roles, Users.role == Roles.id)) \

EDIT:
I tried this select_from(Users.join(Roles, Users.role == Roles.id))
but i got the same result.
the classes that i use are:
from datetime import datetime, date
from typing import Optional, List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, EmailStr

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    email: EmailStr = Field(...)
    username: str
    password: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    birth_date: Optional[date] = None
    student_id: int
    profile_picture: str
    createdon: datetime
    role: int
    disabled: bool

class Roles(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    role: str 


Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

i removed some code that weren't so important  and tried to simplify my answer.

Doesn't seem to make sense.  Can you try print (user.dict.items()) and see if the null columns are in there?  Maybe your str or repr is overloaded and just throwing out the NULL.

Also I don't think that select_from usage will work.  Should be select_from(Users.join(Roles, Users.role == Roles.id))  I think.

If you don't want NULL values, maybe make the column definitions NOT NULL. It would save working around the problem is application programming.

session.exec is a SQLModel feature, not vanilla SQLAlchemy. As you have already been asked, please provide a [mre] so we can reliably reproduce and understand your problem.

so i added the models and the rest of class besides some other similar functions

Guess using schemas could help you! My example uses pydantic but you can actually take namedtuple or something similar instead.
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict


class User(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    id: int
    username: str | None = None
    email: str
    ...


 user = User.model_validate(obj=query_result)

By the way, make sure your join is working as expected.
